# Scala select n-th element of the n-th element of an array / RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD:

```
val a = List((3, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (4, 2.0), (1,0.0))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
```

Ordering the tuple elements by their right hand component in ascending order I would like to:

1. Pick the 2nd smallest result i.e. (3, 1.0)
2. Select the left hand element i.e. 3

The following code does that but it is so ugly and inefficient that I was wondering if someone could suggest something better.

```
val b = ((rdd.takeOrdered(2).zipWithIndex.map{case (k,v) => (v,k)}).toList find {x => x._1 == 1}).map(x => x._2).map(x=> x._1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
implicit val ordering = scala.math.Ordering.Tuple2[Double, Int]

rdd.map(_.swap).takeOrdered(2).max.map { case (k, v) => v }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know `spark`, but maybe a standard method from Scala collections would work?:

```
rdd.sortBy {case (k,v) => v -> k}.apply(2)
```

Comment: Note: there are asymptotically better algorithms for finding n-th smallest thing in a collection. But I guess the current solution be good enough (in many situations).

Answer (score 0):

```
val a = List((3, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (4, 2.0), (1,0.0))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
rdd.map(_.swap).takeOrdered(2).max._2
```